# PHP: SQL query to select columns provided by php array from any table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have array of columns which I want to search from table.

I am looking to use SQL something like :

```
$columns = array('a', 'b', 'c');
$sql = "select $columns from table";
```

Is this possible? How can we perform such action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A part of it is possible:

```
$columns = array('a','b','c');
$sql = "Select ".implode(",", $columns) . " from table....";
```

[PHP implode Manual](http://php.net/manual/de/function.implode.php)

**EDIT**

I'm afraid, it is not possible to exclude the table-name!
But you can query first all table names and then select from those.